# get method with jwt authorization is returning empty object, do we need to decode the jwt token?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, token, decode

**router and controller code is given below:**
tried using jwt decoder, it provides object : {_id, iat, exp} but in postman it return the empty object

````
===router===
 router.get("/secret", requireSignin, (req, res) => {

   res.json({
     user: req.user,
    });
  });
 
 
 ===controller===
 exports.requireSignin = expressJwt({
   secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
   algorithms: ["HS256"],
   userProperty: "auth",
 });```
````

Comment: in POSTMAN, did u pass the token?

Answer (score 0):

For me, this happened when I did not async-await a function that was going to return a signed token that I wrote against a MongoDB schema like this

`const sendCustomerToken = (customer, statusCode, res) => { const token = customer.getSignedToken(); res.status(statusCode).json({ success: true, token }); };`

Basically, it's returning a promise, if you don't await it, it will return a null or empty object because it is procedural
[image: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/Empty]

however if you await it, it waits for the time the string is available then return it like this

`const sendCustomerToken = async (customer, statusCode, res) => { const token = await customer.getSignedToken(); res.status(statusCode).json({ success: true, token }); };`

[image: https://jwt.io/introduction].

schema method

`customerAuthSchema.methods.getSignedToken = async function() { return jwt.sign({ id: this._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRE, }); };`

you may want to check promises in your code where you may be querying the DB.

also if decode is not working, try using **jwt** *sign* **method** which recieves a payload, secret and option - payload is the protected data you want to return, secret is your normal string you can generate using crypto and option is simply the life time of your token. like so

```
function() {
 return jwt.sign({ id: this._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRE, });};`
```

with env variables like this

> PORT=5000
> JWT_SECRET=4de5b205fa171927adb1444c06bd990fadd45ffe7a1309def8b5a JWT_EXPIRE=10min